# How to upgrade elixir version on Ubuntu 18/19

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, asdf-vm

I have these installed:

```
$ asdf list
elixir
  1.6.6
erlang
  20.3.8
```

but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to upgrade my elixir version to 2.x.
I am on Ubuntu, can anyone help?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean - the most up to date version of Elixir is [1.10](https://elixir-lang.org/blog/2020/01/27/elixir-v1-10-0-released/).

In regards to using asdf, you can do following steps:

1. List all available versions: `asdf list-all elixir`
2. You can use one of listed versions, to insall it: `asdf install elixir <version>`
3. Make it be used "globally": `asdf global elixir <version>`
4. Or, temporarily change version: `asdf local elixir <version>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the language, with `asdf` version manager you do not "update" a given installation of a language.

You just install a new version (`asdf install <plugin> <version>`) and remove the old one (`asdf uninstall <plugin> <version>`) if you do not need it anymore.

Additionally you might change your "default" version using `asdf global <package> <version>`.

Learn more about available commands:

https://asdf-vm.com/#/core-commands

Comment: wow it's almost as if they could wrap those commands in an `asdf update` call :)